# how to check gdb server is installed on my embedded pc?

Tags: c, eclipse, ftp, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I am using emebedded pc as the target containing linux RTOS and host as the eclipse ide containing linux RTOS. I am using ftp client to transfer executable from client to the target. 
My question : How to check the gdbserver is there on my target ?
how to run the gdb server ?
could anyone give some information regarding ftp w.r.t this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The below steps will get you started:

1. You should have binary of gdbserver present at your target. Check the same as

   ls -l /usr/bin/gdbserver

   Launch this gdbserver at target using below command

   gdbserver localhost:2001 binarytobedebugged

   GDBSERVER will start listening on port 2001 for all incoming TCP/IP connections.
2. You should have binarytobedebugged with all debug symbols at your host.
3. Connect to gdbserver running at Target from your host using cross compiled GDB

   Run this command at host

   gdb -q binarytobedebuggedWithDebugSymbols

   (gdb) target remote IPofTarget:2001

   (gdb) p var

Rest of commands are all same as with usual GDB Debug session.

I hope this helps.

Comment: should I create a remote system explorer project in eclipse  else just I have to to do some debug configuration ?

Comment: where to add the step 3 in eclipse ide ??

Comment: Maybe this Link can help you with setting up of remote system  project  http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2FlocalVsRemote.html